# Trying to getElementById from a div that loaded with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to getElementById from a div that loaded with ajax, but I can't. Let's explain:

In 'example.php' I have this js code:

```
<script type= "text/javascript">

var page=document.getElementById("table_page").value;

$(document).ready(function() {
    function update() {
      $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: "show_class_entrys.php?q="+page,
       timeout: 1000,
       success: function(data) {
          $("#show_class_entrys_js").html(data); 
          window.setTimeout(update, 3000);
       },
      });
     }
     update();
});


</script>
```

But the input with id='table_page' loading with ajax file 'loaded.php'. The file 'loaded.php' contains this:

```
<?php echo " <input type='hidden' id='table_page' value='7' /> "; ?>
```

This printed somewhere in my 'example.php'. The problem is that I can't get the value from this div in my js code. Please help me.

Comment: The element doesn't exist in the DOM until the AJAX call has completed. You'll need to run whatever functionality relies on the value of `#table_page` inside your `success` callback.

Comment: since your already using jquery, might as well use `$("#table_page").val()` instead of `getElementById`

Comment: Does table_page exist in example.php?

Comment: Also "in 'example.php' I have this js code:". Don't put JS in PHP, it can't be cached and is harder to maintain. Move it to a .js file and use a <script> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var page = '';
    $('#divLoadedID').load('loaded.php', function () {
        page = $("#table_page").val();
        update();
    });

    function update() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "show_class_entrys.php?q=" + page,
            timeout: 1000,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#show_class_entrys_js").html(data);
                window.setTimeout(update, 3000);
            },
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I will try it and then I'll inform you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple fix. All you need to do is overwrite `page` in your success function as it will get the new value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var page=$("#table_page").val();

    function update() {
      $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: "show_class_entrys.php?q="+page,
       timeout: 1000,
       success: function(data) {
          $("#show_class_entrys_js").html(data); 
          window.setTimeout(update, 3000);
          page=$("#table_page").val();
       },
      });
     }
     update();
});
```

The problem is `page` is getting set before the DOM changes, the success part of the ajax call happens after the DOM changes so it can account for new elements/data